# Repeated calling a Haskell monad

Tags: haskell, loops, monad-transformers

I have a Haskell function that returns a monad, declared as follows:

```
data Options = Options {
    optGames :: Int,
    optSuits :: Int,
    optVerbose :: Bool
  } deriving Show

playGame :: Options -> StateT StdGen (WriterT [String] IO)) Bool
```

This function plays a single game of solitaire, then returns a boolean indicating a win or loss, along with a log in the `WriterT` monad.

I would like to call this function a set number of times, each time using the "next" value of the random generator (`StdGen`), and concatenating the `Bool` return values into a list.

I tried creating a recursive function to do the calls, but can't figure out how to pass the monad into each next iteration.

I would like to emulate

```
initial state >>= playGame >>= playGame ... -- repeat N times
```

and collect all of the resulting `Bool` values, as well as the log entries from the `WriterT` monad.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: [Formulate your question as a type.](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?q=Monad+m+%3D%3E+Int+-%3E+m+a+-%3E+m+%5Ba%5D)

Comment: `initial state >>= playGame >>= playGame` is not well-typed. I can guess what you mean, but I can also give better and more confident answers if I don't have to guess :)

Comment: Its not well typed because I still trying to work my way through what the type should be. I've been going through all of the transformer examples that I can find, but Haskell is most definitely the most rigorously mathematical language that I have ever worked in and wrapping my head around some of the examples is hard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you're looking for `replicateM`. This repeats the given action a specified number of times, returning the result as a list. So `replicateM n playGame` corresponds to playing the game `n` times and getting a list of the results back.

Comment: What if I only need the last result? Is there a shorthand for that? Apart from `fmap last`.

Comment: @ron: I can't think of any built-in function to do that, but it should be easy to write yourself.

Comment: I don't understand how `replicateM 1 playGame` is the same as `initialState >>= playGame`. My understanding is that these should be equivalent, but the `initialState` is missing from the version with `replicateM`. What am I missing?